# SVG using css prefers-color-scheme not working with <style> on it on Safari

Tags: css, svg, safari

I have the following svg code on a file, which has a `<style>` element because I'm trying to create a darkmode version of this svg:

```
<svg width="10" height="71" viewBox="0 0 10 71" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <style>

    .gradient {
      stop-color: white;
    }

    @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
      .gradient {
        stop-color: #15181b;
      }
    }

  </style>
<rect width="10" height="71" fill="url(#paint0_linear)"/>
<defs>
  <linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="5" y1="0" x2="5" y2="71" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <stop class="gradient" stop-opacity="0"/>
    <stop class="gradient" offset="1" />
  </linearGradient>
</defs>
</svg>
```

At the moment, this works on every modern browser, except Safari and I haven't been able to find any workaround this. ~~It looks like Safari is not happy using `stop-color` as a CSS rule.~~

Would anyone be familiar with a solution or workaround this? Not sure so far if I can do this differently to accomplish the same thing

**UPDATE**: As @Robert pointed out in the comments, is the @media query what's not working. So to rephrase my question: would it be possible to make this dark mode query somehow work in Safari?

Comment: Are you sure it's that and not the @media rule it doesn't like?

Comment: @RobertLongson ahh... you are correct! It works without the media query. So, I take that might make it impossible to make this media query on Safari?

Comment: Seems not: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=199134

Comment: Thank a lot, @RobertLongson

Answer (score 2):

Safari currently [doesn't support](https://caniuse.com/link-icon-svg) this feature (not even SVG favicons). Your only possibility is to use a bitmap icon and switch the `href` dynamically:

```js
const link = document.querySelector('link[rel="icon"]');
if (matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches) {
  link.href = 'dark.png';
} else {
  link.href = 'light.png';
}
```

You can pair this with dynamically listening for changes:

```js
const link = document.querySelector('link[rel="icon"]');
const mql = matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');
mql.addEventListener('change', () => {
  if (matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches) {
    link.href = 'dark.png';
  } else {
    link.href = 'light.png';
  }
});
```